# How can I make this C++ code shorter? (Coin Change Calculator)

Tags: c++

I'm a C++ beginner. I just made a coin change calculator and now I want the code to be shorter (with a loop or something). How can I do that?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    int amount = 0;
    int result[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int values[4] = { 25, 10, 5, 1 };
    int x = 0;
    std::cout << "Welcome to this super advanced (not) coin change calculator! \n";
    std::cout << "Please enter the amount in cents: ";
    std::cin >> amount;

    x = amount;

    result[0] = x / values[0];
    x = x % values[0];

    result[1] = x / values[1];
    x = x % values[1];

    result[2] = x / values[2];
    x = x % values[2];

    result[3] = x / values[3];
    x = x % values[3];

    std::cout << "Optimal change: " << result[0] << " quarter(s), " << result[1] << " dime(s), " << result[2] << " nickel(s), and " << result[3] << " pennie(s)!";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: your indexing goes 0, 1, 2, 3.

Comment: Are you aware of the concept of loops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few techniques apply

1)   Rather than outputting multiple string literals to `std::cout`, combine all the literals into one, and output that.   Bear in mind that a pair of string literals following each other are combined.   For example, the construct `"ab"  "cd"`  becomes `"abcd"`

2)   Eliminate any variables that are not needed.   In your case, your code reads to `amount`, does an assignment `x = amount`, and then never uses `amount` again.   This means there is an opportunity to eliminate either `amount` (read directly to `x` and proceed from there) or `x`  (don't assign `x = amount`, and then do all operations on `amount`).

3)    If you are reusing logic that only differs by an index such as `result[0] = x/values[0]`  and later `result[1] = x/values[1]`  then consider a loop.

4)    If you have multiple strings to be output (you do!) consider placing them in an array too - then access elements of that array if the loops too.

5)    Don't be afraid to break statements into pieces and re-order operations if it allows you to rationalise.

6)     If we are doing   `x = x op y`  change that to `x op = y`.   For example, change `amount = amount % values[i]` to `amount %= values[i]`.

Putting all that together, you get.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int amount = 0;                 
    int result[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int values[4] = { 25, 10, 5, 1 };
    const char *denom[4] = {"quarter(s),",
                             "dime(s),",
                             "nickel(s), and", 
                             "pennie(s)!"
                           };

    std::cout << "Welcome to this super advanced (not) coin change calculator!\n"     
                 "Please enter the amount in cents: ";           
    std::cin >> amount;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        result[i] = amount / values[i];
        amount %= values[i];
    }
    std::cout << "Optimal change: ";
    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << result[i] << denom[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But we can go further.   In the above, I've broken the initialisation of `denom` into multiple lines for clarity, but the initialisation of the array can be combined into a single line (at some cost of readability)

```
    const char *denom[4] = {"quarter(s),", "dime(s),", "nickel(s), and", "pennie(s)!"};
```

Having done this, we see that can combine the two loops into one if we move the output statement that is between them, and then not actually need the array `result` (elements are only calculated in the loop, and then output).   So we can eliminate that array, and make it a single variable - local to the loop.

```
    std::cout << "Optimal change: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        int result = amount / values[i];
        amount %= values[i];
        std::cout << result << denom[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Having done that, look inside the loop, and note that `result` is only calculated so  we can output it.   So eliminate it by changing the loop to

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << amount/values[i] << denom[i] << " ";
        amount %= values[i];
    }
```

Having done all that, we get

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int amount = 0;                 
    int values[4] = { 25, 10, 5, 1 };
    const char *denom[4] = {"quarter(s),", "dime(s),", "nickel(s), and", "pennie(s)!"};

    std::cout << "Welcome to this super advanced (not) coin change calculator!\n"     
                 "Please enter the amount in cents: ";           
    std::cin >> amount;

    std::cout << "Optimal change: ";

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << amount/values[i] << denom[i] << " ";
        amount %= values[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In doing the above, I've focused on making your code shorter.   I have taken liberties with changing the order in which operations are done, but the output produced will be the same.

There is more that can be done too.  Your code is fairly straight forward, but the C++ standard library includes containers (to manage collections of values) that represent vectors, lists, strings, etc.  These allow you to eliminate raw pointers or raw arrays entirely, and operations (like resizing, inserting elements, removing elements, etc) are handled more cleanly than doing them by hand.  There is also a set of algorithms (in standard header `<algorithm>`) that can operate on every element of containers - if you are writing loops that run over every element of a container (or even a raw array), then there is often (not always) an algorithm that can be used to do the same thing - with more concise code that is easier to read, therefore easier to get right.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the long, detailed answer! Is there a difference between 'string' and 'const char*' ?

Comment: Yes there is a big difference between a `const char *` and a `std::string`.   You could change `denom` from `const char *denom[4] = ...` to being `const std::string denom[4] = ...` (assuming a `#include <string>` is in effect) and the output of the program won't change.   However, the mechanism by that output is produced will be somewhat different, even if the output is the same.   You'll need to read up on pointers and `std::string` to understand the differences between them - and how they can interact (which they can).